# Missing required parameters exception, while param is filled in in URL

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm working on a Laravel project, where I have the following routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], 'prefix' => 'deliver'], function () {
    Route::get("{pitch}/play", "DeliverController@play")->name("deliver.play");
    Route::get('/', 'DeliverController@index')->name('deliver');
});
```

The route named `deliver.play` is being called like this:

```
 <a href="{{ route("deliver.play", $pitch) }}">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Go to Playmode"></span>
 </a>
```

As you can see, I pass the $pitch parameter to the route, however, on execution, the following error pops up:

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
Missing required parameters for [Route: deliver.play] [URI: deliver/{pitch}/play].
```

Which normally means the `{pitch}` param isn't given, however, in the URL bar of my browser the param is there, giving me the complete URL of

`http://localhost:8000/deliver/empty-pitch-13/play`

So how is it possible for Laravel to not see the parameter im passing on to the route? Or is there something that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Edit:

I forgot to add the controller that the route links to. Here it is:

```
    public function play(Pitch $pitch)
    {
        if ($pitch->hasPresentation()) {
            $presentation = head($pitch->presentations);
            return view("deliver.play.index", $presentation);
        }
        return redirect()->route('slides.create', $pitch);
    }
```

Comment: What you're doing looks absolutely fine. How is it you're seeing the URL with the parameter present in your address bar if you're seeing the exception page? Are you sure it's not another line, elsewhere in your view or other views that is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <a href="{{ route('deliver.play', ['pitch' => $pitch]) }}">
```

and add the pitch params to the function like so

```
   Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], 'prefix' => 'deliver'], function () {
   Route::get("{pitch}/play", "DeliverController@play", function($pitch){ 
  // 
  })->name("deliver.play");
   Route::get('/', 'DeliverController@index')->name('deliver');
   });
```

Comment: Didn't change anything in the outcome. I also forgot to mention that the method used in the question, is also used in numerous other routes, where it does work.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the pitch in your params. Try that

Comment: Still gives me the same output

Comment: Sorry, another function with params is to be attached to the route itself.